# How to provide equal distance between a text and the edges of its transparent background in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have some text with a transparent background like so

[image]

Now when the text is small it looks nice and centered (also I have  android:minWidth="150dip") like above but since it is wrap_content when the text is large

[image]

it wraps like this.

Is there a way I can always have a constant space between the edges of the background and the text and also have the text centered(which would be obvious once the sides were fixed)
This is my text xml

```
 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/tocheader"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:minWidth="150dip"
                android:text="example"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
```

and `@drawable/tocheader` is just

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#88000000" />



</shape>
```

Comment: To the downvoter - a reason would be nice, also I've added back sample images of the original problem I had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the padding instead of margin...
Margin gives you space between this view and the surrounding with none of "this view"s properties.
Padding gives you space between this view and surrounding with all of "this view"s properties.

Comment: or using the `RelativeLayout` and the attributes like : `android:layout_alignTop` , `android:layout_alignBottom` , `android:layout_alignRight` and `android:layout_alignLeft`

Comment: @Houcine: That's called over complicating, in this case  
£Slartibartfast: You are most welcome.